# Does intersecting the output of 2 programs give the output of another program?

Tags: computability

Let $S$ be the set of all programs that take integers as input and return integers as output and halt on all inputs. Does there exist a pair of program in $S$, call them $P_1$ and $P_2$, such that there exists no program $P_3$ in $S$ for which the following hold for every integer $y$:

$P_3(x)=y$ for some $x$ iff $P_1(x_1)=y=P_2(x_2)$ for some $x_1$ and $x_2
$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a computable bijection from $\mathbb{N}^*$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. For example, $f(1)=0,f(2)=1,f(3)=-1,f(4)=2,\ldots$

Note a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ is the range of a program if and only if it is [recursively enumerable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_enumerable_language). On the one hand, the range of a program $P$ can be enumerated by running $P(f(1)),P(f(2)),P(f(3)),\ldots$ On the other hand, for a non-empty recursively enumerable subset $X$ of $\mathbb{Z}$, there exists an enumerator $E$ that enumerates $X$. Suppose $E$ requires $n$ steps to output the first number, we can define a program $P$ that $P(i)$ returns the last number outputted by $E$ within at most $\max\{n,f^{-1}(i)\}$ steps.

Since the intersection of two recursively enumerable sets is still recursively enumerable, your $P_3$ exists if and only if the intersection is not empty.

Comment: This is correct, but: 1) your S is not the same S as in the OP, and 2) the OP requested $P_3 \in S$, and you did not prove it halts on all inputs. Indeed, it can not do so when the two ranges are disjoint. The correct answer should be, I think, $P_3$ exists iff the two ranges intersect. (+1 anyway)

Comment: @chi Thanks, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as  $(P1\ range) \cap  (P2\ range)$ is non-empty, their will always be a function p3 in S that has $(P1\ range) \cap (P2\ range)$ as its range. (range is set of all output values for function)

Proof argument goes like this:

Given:

1. $(P1\ range) \cap  (P2\ range)\not= \phi$
2. $S$ is the set of all programs that take integers as input and return integers as output this means:
   for any subset of integers $I\subseteq Z$, 
   there exists a program $P \in S$ such that
   $P:Z\mapsto I$ (this is important inference from definition of S)

Since $(P1\ range) \cap  (P2\ range)\subseteq Z$,

we conclude from 1 and 2 
there exists $p3\in S$,

$p3:Z\mapsto (P1\ range) \cap  (P2\ range)$

I hope this is clear

Comment: thanks for your thoughts on this, I'm looking for a proof , do you have any possible explanation for why this is true

Comment: Why is every subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ the range of some program?

Comment: Why not, we can always write such a program for any subset of Z

Comment: We have only countably many programs, while the subsets of $Z$ are not countable. We won't be able to have any $I\subseteq Z$ as range, but only RE sets. Fortunately, the intersection of two ranges (two RE sets) is RE.

Comment: Your answer also suggests that, if the two ranges are disjoint, then $P_3$ can not exist since $P_3(0)$ would halt (since we require $P_3\in S$) returning an element in the intersection, which can not exist.

Answer (score 0):

No, such a pair of programs does not exist. In other words, a $P_3$ always exists.

On input $x$ just compute $P_1(x)$ and $P_2(x)$. Because both programs halt on all inputs (by their definition), these two computations will stop and provide two results. Then $P_3$ just compares these two results and iff they are equal outputs the result.

Your "programs" are the recursive funtions, and these are known to be closed under intersection.